# Typo in the user preferences - activity data checkbox tooltip

Tags: bug, profile-page, tooltips, spelling

There is a typo in [the user preferences page - Activity data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) checkbox tooltip.

The tooltip text is

> Use On-Site Activity for Relevent Content

The typo in the "**Relevent**", it should be "Relevant"

> [image: Preferences]

Comment: It seems to be fixed already :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As part of the recent [User preferences page responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369403/312043) change, the section was modified and the tooltip is not shown now.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: activity]